# Pi disconnecting from network after bootup

Tags: debian, networking, archlinux, ssh

There seems to be a (very small) time winodw when my pi will let me ssh to it. I got my computer to accept the new key and prompt for my password once (so it **did** connect), but I had forgotten to specify the user and I couldn't log in. Furthermore, the pi usually doesn't respond to ping requests. However, I can see that it has an active IP address on my router. Usually I get the "no route to host" error when I attempt to connect. Is this normal behavior? Do I need a better power supply or is something else wrong?

Note: I'm using the up to date raspbian wheezy image from [here](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian.zip) but I also tried the arch version and that didn't work either.

**UPDATE:** I tried hardwiring my laptop and sshing into my pi from my router but both attempts still produced the "No Route to Host" error.
All the lights flash on the pi, but they eventually all turn off except for the power LED and sometimes the ACT light. From the router, I can see the pi establish anywhere from 0-5 connections during startup. However, they also end up going away.

**UPDATE 2:** I added a python script to my pi's /etc/rc.local file that would connect to my computer (which was running python's simple HTTP server) with wget and then ping my router. However, I never recieved any connections on my computer from the pi so I am beginning to suspect that this is a network/router problem. Are there any router settings that should be enabled for the pi?

Comment: As long as SSH is running it should be available constantly.

Comment: @Jivings That's the problem. I think it stops running right after boot up.

Comment: I think this has been reported before, let me look around.

Comment: What is the output if you try running `ssh -vvv localhost` on the Pi?

Comment: @Jivings I don't have a monitor to see.

Comment: You will have to put a monitor on it. An analog TV should work fine with a SCART to RCA phono adapter. Then at least you can see it boot. I suspect you have a bad image on the SD card.

Comment: @Julian Sorry, I wasn't clear. I have a monitor (and the boot it works fine) but I can't connect to Ethernet and hook it up to my tv at the same time (b/c the tv is in another room). I can reflash the SD and try again but I've already done this multiple times.

Comment: OK, not that then. Could it be your power supply? You need an amp @ 5 V really. Do you have anything plugged in to the USB ports that could be drawing power?

Comment: I believe the power supply is at least 6 V and there's nothing in the USB slots. What's the max V a pi can take safely?

Comment: @Vreality You don't need to connect to ethernet. Just run `ssh -vvv localhost` on the Pi. That will tell you if ssh is running okay.

Comment: Just for arguments sake check the power http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: @AwesomeUser Yes, sorry. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, I had to reinstall raspbian for this to work (I believe that the SD Card's partition had become corrupt from repeated loss of power as I was testing the pi).